# Using lists in a XML file as data for nodes and leaves of an extJS tree

Tags: xml, parsing, extjs, treepanel

I have a xml file that has two lists

```
 <bean id="reportsDef" class="XXXXXXXX">
      <property name="reports">
         <list>
            <value>-Name A</value>
            <value>Name B</value>

            <value>-Name C</value>
            <value>Name D</value>

            <value>-Name E</value>
            <value>Name F</value>
            <value>Name G</value>
         </list>
      </property>
      <property name="reportUrls">
         <list>
           <value></value>
           <value>url B</value>
           <value></value>
           <value>url D</value>
           <value></value>
           <value>url F</value>
           <value>url G</value>
         </list>
      </property>   
   </bean>
```

I want to use these two lists from this xml file to be used as data for an extJS tree.
List "reportsDEF" has titles of nodes and leaves and List "reportUrls" has links that will open on clicking those leaves.
Can anyone please tell me how to do that..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

This format is not ExtJS standard way to create models. So, the goal for you is to create Store and populate it with models based on this XML. How can you achieve it:

1. The best way is to change XML format If you can do it. It should be something like that:

```html
   <root>
      <children>
         <element>
            <leaf>true</leaf>
            <text>detention</text>
         </element>
         <element>
            <children>
               <element>
                  <leaf>true</leaf>
                  <text>book report</text>
               </element>
               <element>
                  <leaf>true</leaf>
                  <text>algebra</text>
               </element>
            </children>
            <expanded>true</expanded>
            <text>homework</text>
         </element>
         <element>
            <leaf>true</leaf>
            <text>buy lottery tickets</text>
         </element>
      </children>
      <expanded>true</expanded>
   </root>
```

2. You can extend `Ext.data.reader.Xml` class and rewrite `readRecords` method. In that method you have to parse your XML manually and return set of models. Here you can the source of that class http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/source/Xml.html#Ext-data-reader-Xml-method-readRecords
3. You can always use `Ext.Ajax.request`(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-method-request) and parse the data manually on `'success'` handler, populate store with parsed data and set it to a treepanel

Comment: So use another approach. The third way is quite easy